# A construction with double "бы"-s

Tags: грамматика

This sentence apparently means "I would like to sleep till April":

> Заснуть бы до апреля бы.

But I can't understand the use of "бы" here. Could someone give examples of other sentences using this double-бы construction? For instance, if I say:

> [Infinitive verb] бы [object] бы.

Does that always mean "I would like to verb the object"?

Comment: You could think of it like of English `like`, which you could put like almost everywhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a kind of "colloquial tautology". In Russian the placement of "*бы*" is not fixed. That is both "Заснуть бы до апреля" and "Заснуть до апреля бы" mean the same. But sometimes the speaker may use a small emphasis to mean either: *I'd like to sleep till April* or *I'd like to sleep, say, until April*.

Colloquially, people sometimes use tautology to express both at once: *Заснуть бы до апреля бы* --> *I'd like to sleep; be my sleep until April*.

Comment: To be clear: does [infinitive verb] + бы always mean "I would like to [verb]"?

Comment: @JackM yes, always.

Comment: @JackM Almost. As it's infinitive it's not confined to 1st person singular. Could also mean something close to: "We would like to [verb], would we?"

Comment: @JackM BTW. You may even omit the verb, if the context allows this: "_Эх, сейчас бы супчику горяченького да с потрошками, а?!_"

Comment: @user4419802 So can you think of "[infinitive] бы" as a contraction of "Хотел [infinitive] бы"?

Comment: @JackM Yes, kind of. Books call this "Желательное значение сослагательного наклонения" (cf. Optativus). More on [Сослагательное наклонение](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3):

I could only think that this adds additional emphasis on the wish the particle *бы* expresses. In normal speech one would simply say:

> Заснуть бы до апреля.

or

> Заснуть до апреля бы.

They are similar, maybe with slight possible differences (emphasis on *заснуть* or *до апреля*).

I would expect double *бы* to be used in poetry, songs and the like, for additional emphasis, rhythm etc.