# Placement of "бы"

Tags: грамматика

I was told that I must say `бы`  in BOTH parts of the sentence and that the placement of it makes no  difference at all. Is the placement of  `бы` critical?

Он `бы` тебе́ понра́вился как то́лько `бы` ты его́ уви́дел.

Он тебе́ `бы` понра́вился как то́лько ты `бы` его́ уви́дел.

Он тебе́ понра́вился `бы` как то́лько ты его́ `бы` уви́дел.

Он тебе́ понра́вился `бы` как то́лько ты его́ уви́дел `бы`.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11008/a-construction-with-double-%d0%b1%d1%8b-s

Comment: once again, please, don't use uppercase in such cases

Comment: It wasn't a duplicate sentence but it was very close. My example which was in question was not the same and it was much more specific in terms of word order. I also prefer uppercase because it is easier to read _for me_ whenever I make documents for others or ones for myself but I will obey the rules of the site per your request.

Answer (score 3):

The neutral, unmarked, default form is

> Он БЫ тебе́ понра́вился, как то́лько ты БЫ его́ уви́дел.

Also, I think you need a comma before как.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was also recently told that "бы" has to be said/placed immediately before or immediately after "ты" or else the sentence will sound unnatural.

Comment: @Штефан in this sentence if you put it before ты, it follows только. So it can be confused with the idiom только бы.

Answer (score 2):

Сritical to style maybe, but not critical to meaning, i believe the placement is only dictated by considerations of smooth flow of the sentence and maybe convenience of the speaker, which obviously may vary between different people.

Comment: One million "thank you's" to you!